# How do I get my hard drive's space back?

Tags: hard-drive

I have formatted my external 2T hard drive and now when I try to move a 7G file onto it it says that item can’t be copied because it is too large for the volume's format, even though when I check how much free space the hard drive has it says I still have 2T. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you formatted your hard drive as FAT32, which only accepts file less than 4G. What is your current operating system? You could try to reformat it to NTFS

Comment: The limitation is less than 4GB, I believe. But regardless, this is the answer.

Comment: @ta.speot.is thanks for pointing it out. not sure why I typed 2G in the first place